# Laravel collect($array)->sortBy($value)->values() Is showing on screen

Tags: arrays, laravel, sorting, laravel-5, collections

I have a little problème on sorting an array according to a value using **Laravel**, what i did is converting it into a collection with:

```
$array = collect($array)
```

Then i sorted it with:

```
$array = collect($array)->sortBy($sortingValue)
```

The result here is a collection, so the next step was to get my data as an array back again:

```
$array = collect($array)->sortBy($sortingValue)->values()
```

I then wrote this code between semicolons because it's nested in an html code, so got something like this:

```
{{$array = collect($array)->sortBy($sortingValue)->values()}}
```

This is working pretty good, i do have my array sorted according to the parameter i pasted to the function,  the problem i have is that this is causing the results to show up on my page in a text format, at the place im executing this code!

Any idea on where this comes from ? im pretty sure it's because of the nested code, but i didn't figure out how to hide that text from my page, and only use the results for the rest of my project.

Thank you.

Comment: between semicolons?  also why the blade echo tags for a php statement like that?

Comment: @lagbox Cause it's nested in a html file, is'nt the right way for doing that ?

Comment: `; ... ;`   semicolons? just trying to figure out what semicolons have to do with this at the moment :)

Comment: @lagos, if i dont put them, the code only ouputs the operation as a string..

Comment: @YacineSidiAttallah Semicolons are `;`, braces are `{` and `}`; you're using the wrong word to describe your problem.

Comment: what "semicolons" .. where

Comment: @TimLewis, it worked ! Yeah exactly, sorry trying to translate from french, I actually tought the {{}} replaced the @ php tag ! Thank's for the answer :)

Comment: @lagos semicolons for me means braces, didn't know how to translate it from french.. but, as i said in the previous comment, tought the braces(semicolons for me lol) actually replace the @ php tag, thank's for your contribution :)

Comment: In pretty much every case, you can use `{{ }}` instead of `<?php ?>`, but you have to remember that `{{ $var }}` has additional functionality built in, and is equivalent to `<?php echo e($var); ?>`. On the other hand, `@php ... @endphp` is literally `<?php ... ?>`, and should be used if you don't want to echo/loop/etc.

Comment: nice ... enjoy using laravel :-)

Comment: @TimLewis Thank's for the clarification, very helpful, didn't know about that !

Comment: @lagbox Thank u :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `{{ }}` to assign a variable is not the correct approach, as it is shorthand for `echo`ing (printing) the code to your view. If you want to assign a variable in a `.blade.php` file, use the `@php` directive, or raw PHP tags:

```
@php $array = collect($array)->sortBy($sortingValue)->values(); @endphp
<?php $array = collect($array)->sortBy($sortingValue)->values(); ?>
```

Then, later in your code, you can do:

```
@foreach($array as $record){
  {{ $record->id }}
  ...
@endforeach
```

(or any other, valid property)

Comment: Thank's a lot :)

Comment: No problem :) One final consideration, if you can define this conversion/sort inside the Controller, and pass it to the view from there, it'll clean up your code a little (although sometimes it's impossible to avoid, just a thought)

Comment: @TimLwis, clearly a good idea, in this project, i'm actually taking back other's developer code, so a bit complicated to refactor all of it at this point, but clearly the way to go in my future projects :)

Comment: Ah, quite understandable; refactoring and writing new code require separate approaches sometimes, I get that. As long as you're aware of the options moving forward, and what is and isn't good practice, etc. then you're fine :)

Comment: Exactly, thank's again @TimLewis, also for teaching me english haha !